# Как выровнять маркеры в списке?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть список `<input type='radio'>`, к которому применен стиль `list-style: lower-alpha;`. Также используется Bootstrap версии 3. Маркеры выглядят ужасно, и хотелось бы выровнять их.

Пример того, как это выглядит, [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/5twuncde/).

Как это сделать правильно?

```
<div class="container" role="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="questions">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                             <h3>Question 1</h3>   
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="question">
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="answer" /> <span class="answer">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC</span>    
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="answer" /> <span class="answer">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC</span>   
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="answer" /> <span class="answer">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC</span>   
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="answer" /> <span class="answer">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC</span>    
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавь

```
li .radio label{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Результат

```css
li {
    list-style: lower-alpha;
}
li .radio label{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" role="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="questions">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                             <h3>Question 1</h3>

                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="question">
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="answer" /> <span class="answer">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC</span>

                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="answer" /> <span class="answer">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC</span>

                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="answer" /> <span class="answer">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC</span>

                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="answer" /> <span class="answer">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC</span>

                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L5mwaqyo/

Comment: Помогло спасибо